# funcion para cambiar los numeros a letras en php

Tags: php

En php debo crear una función querecibiendo un numero entero lo pase a letra, por ejempo, 3, tres

```
<?php
    function numerosyletras($numero1){
        $numero1 = "356";
        $conversion = "tres cinco seis";
        echo $conversión;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Cuál es el error con el código?

Answer (score 1):

Una posibilidad es utilizar la función str_replace para reemplazar una cadena con una lista personalizada de valores.
Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
function numeroAletras($numero){
$numeros = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
$letras = ["cero ","uno ","dos ", "tres ", "cuatro ","cinco ","seis ","siete ","ocho ","nueve "];
return str_replace($numeros, $letras, $numero);
}

echo numeroAletras("14569"); // uno cuatro cinco seis nueve
```